# How to save using condition in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Basically I want to save data in my model using condition to prevent multiple save data being performed simultaneously.

What I currently do now is:

```
$order = Order::find(id);
$order->paid_amount = $amount;
$order->status = $status;
$order->save();
```

What I need is:

```
$order = Order::find(id);
$order->paid_amount = $amount;
$order->status = $status;
$order->where('last_update', $last_update);
$order->save();
```

Is it possible to do this in laravel efficiently or do I have to use raw sql or update?

Comment: you can simply use an if condition `if($order->where('last_update', $last_update)) `  then save

Comment: Won't that still be able to cause inconsistent data since retrieving and saving data in the database is not in one sql update syntax?

Comment: all statements will be inserted/updated once you call `save`

Comment: What I mean is instead of creating two sql in laravel like select order; update order; isn't creating update order where last_update = 2015/15/11 12:10:01 more safe to prevent multiple edit?

Comment: may be you want this `updateOrCreate()`

Comment: I don't want to create sql, the order is already exist, I just want to update the order status and prevent it to be changed in case the order status has been changed by the other user. basically I just want to create update order_status where id=something and last_updated=something

Comment: i dont think that's possible because to update a record you first need to know even it exists or not otherwise how can you predict it? not possible. db will be hit two times.

Comment: @Adamnick But you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with only one hit.

Comment: @Amarnasan how do you do that in laravel

Comment: @Adamnick With raw SQL, I guess... Everything is possible with raw SQL. Ugly as f**k, though.

Comment: yeah that's why i love eloquent. @Amarnasan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean "Is it possible to do this in **eloquent** efficiently or do I have to use raw sql or update?"

Anyway, I think you need the query builder to do what you want:

```
DB::table('order')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->update([
         'paid_amount' => $amount,
         'status' => $status;
      ]);
```

It is as atomic as you can get.

Answer (score 3):

A simplified version of the @Amarnasan answer:

```
Order::findOrFail($id)->update([
     'paid_amount' => $amount,
     'status' => $status;
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way to do this :

```
$order = Order::where('last_update', $last_update)->find($id);
$order->paid_amount = $amount;
$order->status = $status;
$order->save();
```

Comment: It works for 99.99% only. during line 2, 3, the row can be changed in DB, and result becomes wrong.